# How to track a customer only bug

Tags: debugging

Scenario:

A customer is reporting bugs in a near useless fashion "sometimes when i press button A it does not work".

There story is constantly changing every time you talk to them "button A seems to go wrong after pressing button B" "now button A goes wrong after pressing button C" "Button A goes wrong irrespective of buttons B and C it was all just coincidence"

I have a test rig in my office and can see button A working perfectly, i have never had any issue and cannot replicate the customers problem no matter how many times i try.

management are 120% sure the issue is in the code, no chance that the issue is with the customers button A hardware.

What steps can be taken to trace this issue ? What do you do to show you have covered all possible bases before informing management the code is not the problem and you cannot fix it.

Edit: the software is embedded firmware not an application running on a computer.

Comment: Can you watch the customer reproduce the issue?  Maybe turn on some debug logging in the customer's application to get more detailed information from them?  (If the application doesn't have detailed logging, you'd have to add it first.)

Comment: Customer is on the other side of the world sadly and its an embeded firmware so little to no logging of any kind only LED indicators.

Answer (score 0):

As your customer is on the other side of the world I'm guessing your office hours are different and that's what makes it difficult to see what they're doing remotely. If the office hours isn't an issue, then you could ask them to let you watch their screen whilst they attempt to reproduce the issue. Software which could help this remote viewing process includes:

Join.me (FREE)- http://join.me

LogMeIn - https://secure.logmein.com/

GoToAssist - http://www.gotoassist.co.uk/remote_support/

amongst others.

If remote viewing isn't a possibility, another option might be to ask them to record the process, by using Steps Recorder (this is built in to Windows 7 & 8, so only useful if they're using one of these). A guide on how to run it is available here:

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/problem-steps-recorder.htm

They could then send you this file which would mean you could see exactly what they're doing and what the outcome is.

Comment: problem is its embedded firmware not an application on a computer

Comment: Sorry I missed that in your comments, totally different scenario. I guess the main problem you're having is a lack of cohesion in the information you're getting from the customer - unfortunately it might mean having to simply tell them that you're unable to reproduce the problem at your end with the supported hardware and that you need more specific details as to the events leading up to the issue. Perhaps they could record the process with a cameraphone just so you can be certain how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Alternatively you could write a test plan based on the events they've listed to reproduce the issue, and show that you've tested the same sequence of events without errors. That way they'd have to acknowledge that either there is a local hardware issue or they've got the details of how to reproduce it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Often what's going wrong is that the customer is omitting some detail that seems insignificant to them (always makes sure to submerge everything in water before use, for example), but is actually the other part of the cause. Ideally, you want as much detail as possible. If practical, visit in person to see the bug in action. If not, see if they can make a video recording of start to finish.